# Something wrong with inserting random numbers into an array - user game

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a bingo game in ruby for the console, and I have a board that gets random generated numbers on it for each user.  However, for every user it generates the same random board.  Effectively @places, gets put in array @bingo_cards.  But instead of being two different hashes of numbers, they end up the same.  There is something wrong with my method below.

The first method sets up the board, and the second method picks numbers for it

```
def start_game(user_goes_first)
#bingo slots
@places = { 
  a1:" ",a2:" ",a3:" ", a4:" ", a5:" ",
  b1:" ",b2:" ",b3:" ", b4:" ", b5:" ",
  c1:" ",c2:" ",c3:" ", c4:" ", c5:" ",
  d1:" ",d2:" ",d3:" ", d4:" ", d5:" ",
  e1:" ",e2:" ",e3:" ", e4:" ", e5:" "
}
@places_keys = [
  :a1,:a2,:a3,:a4,:a5,
  :b1,:b2,:b3,:b4,:b5,
  :c1,:c2,:c3,:c4,:c5,
  :d1,:d2,:d3,:d4,:d5,
  :e1,:e2,:e3,:e4,:e5
]

@bingo_cards = []



@user_name.each do |numbers|

  @places_keys.each_with_index do |n,i| 
    @places[n] = pick_number(i)

  end
   @bingo_cards << @places
   p @bingo_cards
 end
 user_turn
end

def pick_number(num)
 #generates random numbers that make up the bingo board(s)
      case num
      when 0..5
        rand(1..15)
      when 6..10
        rand(16..30)
      when 11..12
        rand(16..30)
      when 13
        "X"
      when 14..15
        rand(16..30)
      when 16..20
        rand(31..45)
      when 21..25
        rand(46..60)
      else
        0 
      end
end

 def draw_game
   puts ""
   puts ""
   puts "     B   I   N  G  O".gray
   puts ""
@bingo_cards.each do |bingo|
  puts " 1   #{@places[:a1]} | #{@places[:b1]} | #{@places[:c1]} | #{@places[:d1]} | #{@places[:e1]}".green
  puts "    --- --- --- --- ---"
  puts " 2   #{@places[:a2]} | #{@places[:b2]} | #{@places[:c2]} | #{@places[:d2]} | #{@places[:e2]}".green
  puts "    --- --- --- --- ---"
  puts " 3   #{@places[:a3]} | #{@places[:b3]} | #{@places[:c3]} | #{@places[:d3]} | #{@places[:e3]}".green
  puts "    --- --- --- --- ---"
  puts " 4   #{@places[:a4]} | #{@places[:b4]} | #{@places[:c4]} | #{@places[:d4]} | #{@places[:e4]}".green
  puts "    --- --- --- --- ---"
  puts " 5   #{@places[:a5]} | #{@places[:b5]} | #{@places[:c5]} | #{@places[:d5]} | #{@places[:e5]}".green
  put_line
end
```

end

Example output:  Michael

```
 1   8 | 13 | 17 | 18 | 31
--- --- --- --- ---
 2   3 | 29 | 25 | 40 | 47
--- --- --- --- ---
 3   7 | 28 | 30 | 38 | 49
--- --- --- --- ---
 4   14 | 28 | X | 41 | 57
--- --- --- --- ---
 5   7 | 25 | 27 | 33 | 59
```

Sean
Michael

```
 1   8 | 13 | 17 | 18 | 31
--- --- --- --- ---
 2   3 | 29 | 25 | 40 | 47
--- --- --- --- ---
 3   7 | 28 | 30 | 38 | 49
--- --- --- --- ---
 4   14 | 28 | X | 41 | 57
--- --- --- --- ---
 5   7 | 25 | 27 | 33 | 59
```

I don't think how I am generating the random numbers is the issue:  here is the array of the numbers.  For some reason there array of random numbers one which is random and the other which is not.

Here is the printed @bingo_cards, which is where things appear to go wrong:

```
  [{:a1=>7, :a2=>3, :a3=>8, :a4=>2, :a5=>11, :b1=>1, :b2=>22, :b3=>29, :b4=>25, :b5=>28,   :c1=>29, :c2=>17, :c3=>17, :c4=>"X", :c5=>25, :d1=>16, :d2=>43, :d3=>31, :d4=>35, :d5=>34, :e1=>44, :e2=>57, :e3=>52, :e4=>59, :e5=>51}]
   [{:a1=>8, :a2=>3, :a3=>7, :a4=>14, :a5=>7, :b1=>13, :b2=>29, :b3=>28, :b4=>28, :b5=>25, :c1=>17, :c2=>25, :c3=>30, :c4=>"X", :c5=>27, :d1=>18, :d2=>40, :d3=>38, :d4=>41, :d5=>33, :e1=>31, :e2=>47, :e3=>49, :e4=>57, :e5=>59}, {:a1=>8, :a2=>3, :a3=>7, :a4=>14, :a5=>7, :b1=>13, :b2=>29, :b3=>28, :b4=>28, :b5=>25, :c1=>17, :c2=>25, :c3=>30, :c4=>"X", :c5=>27, :d1=>18, :d2=>40, :d3=>38, :d4=>41, :d5=>33, :e1=>31, :e2=>47, :e3=>49, :e4=>57, :e5=>59}]
```

Comment: What is @user_name, and how is it set?

Comment: Nevermind, I see the problem.

Comment: As a hash, places has a method called keys already. No need to make your own by hand. Could have just said `@places_keys = @places.keys`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a hash object in an array, then change the original hash object, those changes are reflected in the array since the object in the array is the same object.

```
:001 > h = {}
 => {} 
:002 > h[:a1] = 1
 => 1 
:003 > h[:a2] = 2
 => 2 
:004 > arr = []
 => [] 
:005 > arr << h
 => [{:a1=>1, :a2=>2}] 
:006 > h[:a2] = 4
 => 4 
:007 > arr
 => [{:a1=>1, :a2=>4}]
```

You probably want to put a copy of the hash object into the array. Use the `dup` or `clone` method to make a shallow copy (which is all you need here).

```
:016 >   arr = []
 => [] 
:017 > h
 => {:a1=>1, :a2=>4} 
:018 > arr << h.dup
 => [{:a1=>1, :a2=>4}] 
:019 > h[:a1] = 15
 => 15 
:020 > arr
 => [{:a1=>1, :a2=>4}] 
:021 > h
 => {:a1=>15, :a2=>4}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) How does the code you posted produce the output you posted?

2) Your start_game method never uses its parameter variable.  Get rid of it.

3) I don't think the following accomplishes anything:

```
@places = { 
  a1:" ",a2:" ",a3:" ", a4:" ", a5:" ",
  b1:" ",b2:" ",b3:" ", b4:" ", b5:" ",
  c1:" ",c2:" ",c3:" ", c4:" ", c5:" ",
  d1:" ",d2:" ",d3:" ", d4:" ", d5:" ",
  e1:" ",e2:" ",e3:" ", e4:" ", e5:" "
}
```

...so delete it.  If for some reason having a hash like that is necessary, just do:

```
@places = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = " "}
```

3) I'm not even sure why you are using a Hash for your board.  It seems like it would make things easier if you used an array of arrays:

```
[
   [......],   #each row is an array
   [......],
   [......],
   [......],
   [......],
]
```

To create a 5x5 array of random numbers, you can do this:

```
cols = 5
rows = 5

places = []
count = 0

rows.times do |i|
  row = []

  cols.times do |j|
    row << pick_number(count)
    count += 1
  end

  places << row
end
```

4) For the output, do you really want to transpose the columns into rows?  If so,

```
output = places.transpose
```

Then all these lines:

```
 puts " 1   #{@places[:a1]} | #{@places[:b1]} | #{@places[:c1]} | #{@places[:d1]} | #{@places[:e1]}".green
  puts "    --- --- --- --- ---"
  puts " 2   #{@places[:a2]} | #{@places[:b2]} | #{@places[:c2]} | #{@places[:d2]} | #{@places[:e2]}".green
  puts "    --- --- --- --- ---"
  puts " 3   #{@places[:a3]} | #{@places[:b3]} | #{@places[:c3]} | #{@places[:d3]} | #{@places[:e3]}".green
  puts "    --- --- --- --- ---"
  puts " 4   #{@places[:a4]} | #{@places[:b4]} | #{@places[:c4]} | #{@places[:d4]} | #{@places[:e4]}".green
  puts "    --- --- --- --- ---"
  puts " 5   #{@places[:a5]} | #{@places[:b5]} | #{@places[:c5]} | #{@places[:d5]} | #{@places[:e5]}".green
  put_line
end
```

can be reduced to:

```
output.each_with_index do |row, i|
  row.unshift i+1

  strs = row.map do |num|
    num.to_s.center(4)
  end

  puts strs.join("|") 
  puts "---  " * (cols+1)

end
```

...which will get you something like this:

```
 1  | 1  | 1  | 28 | 27 | 44 
---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  
 2  | 1  | 16 | 16 | 31 | 53 
---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  
 3  | 8  | 29 | 17 | 35 | 56 
---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  
 4  | 15 | 24 | X  | 37 | 49 
---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  
 5  | 10 | 17 | 24 | 37 | 55 
---  ---  ---  ---  ---  ---
```